# Is it possible to create map packages for ArcMap version 10 using 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, map-package

Is it possible to create a map package in an older version? Currently I am using 10.1 and the client uses 10.0. Can you create a map package for different versions?

I see you can create layer packages using Python for different versions but you cannot specify the version when creating a map package. As I don't have 10.0 I can't test whatever I create these.

When you unpack the file using ArcCatalog does it create it v.10. and 10.1?

Can you create the original file in 10.0?

Answer (score 8):

Map Packages from ArcGIS 10.1 to ArcGIS 10.0

It is possible through the

**Package Map (Data Management)** Version [Optional]

Specifies the version of the geodatabases that will be created in the resulting package. Specifying a version allows packages to be shared with previous versions of ArcGIS and supports backward compatibility.

```
ALL — Package will contain geodatabases and a map document compatible with all versions. (10.0 and higher)
CURRENT — Package will contain geodatabases and a map document compatible with the version of the current release.
10.1 —Package will contain geodatabases and a map document compatible with version 10.1.
10 —Package will contain geodatabases and a map document compatible with version 10.0.
```

Full Official Documentation

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q5000000

Answer (score -1):

```
PackageMap_management('in_map.mxd', 'output_pack.mpk', "PRESERVE", "CONVERT_ARCSDE", "#", "ALL", "RUNTIME", "NOT_REFERENCED", "ALL")
```

ALL keeps compatibility with 10.0 and 10.1, you could change it to 10 for only 10.0 compatibility.

Edit: New here, but how is this not helpful? It does exactly what he asked for.

Comment: Mapperz had already posted what your proposed.  Read his post and you will see the ALL option was already indicated.  Welcome to the site in any event.